# как сделать по середине кнопку в kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

делаю приложение и мне надо примерно сделать на Lebel кнопку по середине но почему то pos_hitnt не работает.

navigationdrawer: https://yadi.sk/d/1NaSn8czi2WhiA

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
# from kivymd.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
from navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


main_widget_kv = '''
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Toolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: 'Welcome'
        background_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.nav_drawer.toggle()]]
        #right_action_items: [['more-vert', lambda x: app.raised_button.open(self.parent)]]
    Label:
        Button:
            text: "We Will"
            #pos_hitnt:(0.2,0.2)
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5






'''

class NavigateApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_string(main_widget_kv)
        #self.nav_drawer = Navigator()
        return main_widget

NavigateApp().run()
```

Comment: Кнопка в Kivy и есть лейбл, только с возможностью назначить действие, не нужно добавлять кнопку в лейбл, не уверен, что это вообще возможно. Во-вторых, чтобы поставить элемент посередине, pos_hint должен быть 0.5, а не 0.2. Ну и в-третьих - у вас там ошибка в самом написании `pos_hint`

Comment: И, в-четвертых, зачем использовать старую версию KivyMD?

Comment: можно ссылку на новую версию KivyMD?